# Core Data setting One-To-Many in XCode 4.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, relational-database

I'm trying to understand how to set up a one-to-many relationship in Xcode 4.3.1. Usually there was a Utilities pane with a "Plural" option, but I can't find it anymore. Does anyone know if this option was move somewhere else?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Guess that's what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Ah ha ! Apparently you also have to add a Relationship , otherwise the "Relationship" panel doesn't even show up. Thanks man :)