# How to correctly configure CoreData datamodel and NSManagedObjects for a to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

How to correctly configure CoreData datamodel and NSManagedObjects for a to-many relationship?
I feel i have misconfigured the xcdatamodeld file, but I can't find what's wrong.
I generated a new single view project with CoreData selected. The following code is a simple as I can explain the problem.

```
Parent *parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent"      inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

Child *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];    

child.parent = parent;
```

When i call

```
[parent.children count];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Child count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7450370'

When I call

```
NSMutableSet *children = [parent mutableSetValueForKey:@"children"];
```

'NSManagedObjects of entity 'Parent' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'children''

Also, there doesn't seem to be any generated add/remove methods being generated to modify the children collection such as

```
- (void)addChildObject:(Child *)value;
- (void)removeChildObject:(Child *)value;
```

### xcdatamodeld

Entities

- Child
  relationship: parent
  destination: Parent
  inverse: children
- Parent
  relationship: children
  destination: Child
  inverse: parent
- Configurations (Default)
  entity: Child
  class: Child

  entity: Parent
  class: Parent

### Parent.h

```
@interface Parent : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *children;
@end
```

### Parent.m

```
@implementation Parent
  @dynamic children;
@end
```

### Child.h

```
@interface Child : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *parent;
@end
```

### Child.m

```
@implementation Child
  @dynamic parent;
@end
```

Comment: Did you write the files Parent.m/h, Child.m/h yourself or are they generated in Xcode with "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." ? Have you double-checked that "children" is defined as "To-Many Relationship" in the Core Data Inspector?

Comment: I had a few goes at writing parent/child. I tried generating and writing from scratch. I didn't realise the Core Data Inspector had that information. That seems to have done the trick @MartinR. If you want to write that as an answer, I will accept it and annotate in comments with my details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." in Xcode to create the managed object subclass files. This ensures that you have the correct accessor functions. Another advantage is that Xcode then knows the accessor functions and does autocompletion.

Make also sure that the `children` relationship is defined as "To-Many Relationship" in the Core Data Inspector.

Comment: Thanks. Setting the to-many relationship in Xcode solved the problem. It can be found by selecting a relationship in the xcdatamodeld file and clicking on the right-most inspector. I only previously looked at this inspector when clicking on entities (not relationships).

Comment: Here's where to set the To Many relationship in Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933689/core-data-setting-one-to-many-in-xcode-4-3-1

Answer (score 0):

Using an iPad now so my code isn't handy. I just did this last week and what I did was to follow Apples instruction to the letter, using the Core Data programming guide - the many to many instruction are near the end and referenced in the table of contents.

I then used Xcode to create the object templates, and used the generated mutable method Xcode created to add the objects.

I'll have access to my code later leave a comment if you want me to post the exact lines where I make a many to many association.

EDIT: So what I see in the graph view of the Core Data model is two objects connected by double arrows on both sides - this will tell you you got it wired properly. Then, in the generated code, I have a method that Xcode generated for me:

```
- (void)addProductsObject:(Product *)value;
```

In my app there are Orders that have Products, and this is a many to many as you would imagine. Its all working properly. When you make the association you just need to do it once (like in the above, I add a Product to an Order and the Order to Product association happens automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have generated the classes using xcode rather than writing them from scratch. That sounds like it would have helped me. Setting the to-many relationship directly fixed the crashes though.